# creating dynamic list based on file in NSDocumentDirectory with dynamic gesture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I need to create a list of all the files in the document directory (that match a pattern if possible) place the file names if a scrollable UI and attached a gesture to each file name. In other words i need to create like a file dialog, if i may; that the user can select the file and upon tapping the file name i trigger some method.

My thinking is to use the following:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSString *currentpath;
NSArray *filelist;
int count;
int i;

filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

filelist = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: @"/tmp" error: nil];

count = [filelist count];

for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        NSLog (@"%@", [filelist objectAtIndex: i]);
```

The part with i find more challenging is to place the file list names in a scrollable UI,like in uilabel for each name and then make each label have a gesture so when the user tap it it will trigger a method.

any idea\draft\sample code would be great.
TIA.

Comment: ok, How about adding a gesture to a label created programatically.. that would help.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I resolve it by connecting the label to a tap gesture in the code, here is a small sample:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gesturTP = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(switchTP)];  [lblTaxPayer addGestureRecognizer:gesturTP]; 
    [gesturTP release];
```

while the labels created and hooked to the scroll view dynamically.

Hope it helps, if anyone needs me to elaborate more let me know.
Thanks